# Consider two distributions $P(·)$ and $Q(·)$ on the alphabet ...

Tags: probability, information-theory

Consider two distributions $P(·)$ and $Q(·)$ on the alphabet $\chi = \{a_1 , a_2 ... , a_k \}$ such that $Q(a_i) \gt 0 $ show that:

$\sum_{i = 1}^n  \frac{P(a_i)^2}{Q(a_i)} \ge 1 $

Comment: Sum of non-negative numbers is????

Comment: Are you certain of the question? As stated, it is trivial.

Comment: (also, your indices do not match, the sum should start at 1 and not 0.)

Comment: Thanks alot for your attention. I jyst edited the post. Sorry for typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the expectation under the $P$-measure:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {P(a_i)^2} {Q(a_i)} 
= E\left[\frac {P(A)} {Q(A)}\right] 
= E\left[\left(\frac {Q(A)} {P(A)}\right)^{-1}\right] 
\geq E\left[\frac {Q(A)} {P(A)}\right]^{-1} 
= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {Q(a_i)} {P(a_i)} P(a_i) = 1 $$

where the inequality follows from Jensen's inequality. WLOG the inverse operation is valid as we can assume all $P(a_i) > 0$; if not we just simply discard the term as we are taken expectation under the $P$-measure.